# One db per user and security

Tags: security, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying  to implement an app which uses couchdb as backend, But  the problem is,
When installing couchdb , couchdb allows anyone to enter couchdb and create/delete/update databases, so we configure admin(super admin) for the  couchdb server to prevent anonymous And if we configure superadmin while installing couchdb server, then normal users can't create databases, so userdb for the user isn't created. Only super admin has privilege to create database in couchdb. Even users with 'admins' role can't create  db in couchdb.

Comment: Hi @Roshan, could you be more specific as for what your question is?

Comment: Hi @toti08, I've configured server admin for my couchdb server and when i tried to create user db from the app I get "you are not server admin " response .

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. You're right, only the server admin can create a database. Normally, when creating a user, you query your remote server(API) and it will create the user database as well as the actual user.

Comment: @toti08 Then  how can we achieve one db per user, if normal user can't create database ?

Answer (score 3):

I just dealt with all of this myself and couldn't find hardly anything about it...

From the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/intro/security.html?highlight=curl%20-x%20put%20_users#authentication-database):

> Users may only access (`GET /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan`) or modify (`PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan`) documents that they own

This means that users can add themselves to the _users db.  Thus, if you have [couch_peruser](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/config/couch-peruser.html) turned on, running the following `curl` command will create the user `jan` along with the `userdb-6a616e` database.

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"name": "jan", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

You can use the [db.signUp()](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/api.md#dbsignupusername-password--options--callback) function from the [PouchDB Authentication](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/) plugin to effectively do the same thing.  Also, I had to manually encode the username when initially creating my `db` var for the new remote PouchDB instance:

```
function encode (str) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
        .split('').map(function (v) {
            return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
        }).join('')
}

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/userdb-' + encode(username), {
    auth: {
        username: username,
        password: username
    },
    skip_setup: true // Because the DB won't exist initially
})
```